# Why does my dynamic IEqualityComparer not work?

Tags: c#, linq, comparison

I have a class

```
public class Foo
{
  public int ID { get; set; }
}
```

and I've implemented a LinqEqualityComparer to allow dynamic IEqualityComparer tests for the Except extenion method.

```
public class LinqEqualityComparer<T> : IEqualityComparer<T>
{
    protected Func<T, T, bool> Comparison { get; set; }

    public LinqEqualityComparer(Func<T, T, bool> comparison)
    {
        Comparison = comparison;
    }

    public bool Equals(T x, T y)
    {
        return Comparison(x, y);
    }


    public int GetHashCode(T obj)
    {
        return obj.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

I've created the following code to test it:

```
IEnumerable<Foo> settings = new Foo[]
{
  new Foo{ID = 1},
  new Foo{ID = 2}
};
IEnumerable<Foo> currentSettings = new Foo[]
{
  new Foo{ID = 1},
  new Foo{ID = 2},
  new Foo{ID = 3}
};
IEqualityComparer<Foo> comparer = new LinqEqualityComparer<Foo>((x, y) => x.ID == y.ID);
IEnumerable<Foo> missing = currentSettings.Except(settings, comparer);
```

However Foos 1,2 and 3 are all present in the 'missing' variable.

Why does this LinqEqualityComparer not work?

Comment: Side note, this should probably have a slightly different name; the idea here is to define a comparer from a delegate (or more commonly a lambda).  While this is somewhat related to LINQ, it doesn't need to be.  There are plenty of places outside of LINQ that take a comparer where this type can be useful, so I'd consider giving it a different name.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because your equality comparer does not implement `GetHashCode` correctly. The `GetHashCode` implementation **must** produce the same code for elements that compare equal. This does not happen here because the equality comparison is customized while the hash codes are not generated accordingly.

To make this work you would need to do one of two things:

1. Make the comparer accept the hash code implementation as an additional argument, i.e. `x => x.ID.GetHashCode()` and forward to that. This is easiest and what you should do in practice.
2. Modify `GetHashCode` in such a way that it is an aggregate function of the hash codes of the properties that take part in the comparison (here that is the `ID` property) -- a straight xor of the individual hash codes would work (even though it might not be optiomal).

   That leaves you with the problem of how to detect which
   properties are compared. To be able to answer that question automatically you would need to accept an expression tree instead of a delegate for the comparison, i.e. an `Expression<Func<T, T, bool>>` and then visit the expression tree to determine what to do. That's bound to not be easy going.

Comment: Jon, that makes sense - so should I also pass in an appropriate hash func?

Comment: @Liath yes, the constructor would need a `Func<T, int>` delegate passed in too that is paired with the corresponding `comparison` delegate that generated proper hash codes.

Comment: To your edit, his `GetHashCode` implementation should just be `x => x.ID.GetHashCode()`.  That's all...

Comment: @Liath: Yes, that's easiest. I have outlined an alternative "automatic" approach, but it's best seen as an exercise rather than good practice.

Comment: @Jon Your edit talks about XORing hash codes together to create an aggregate, which simply isn't appropriate in this context.

Comment: @Servy: I think it's better now, agree?